# is it possible to change the childPosition id of the expandablelistview?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

just want to know if it is possible to change the childPosition id of the expandablelistview?

because i want to change the childPosition id to my category id..

this is my DataChild, i already get categories name but i also want to get the categories id. how do i do that?

```
List<String> CATEGORY = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=0;i<categories.length();i++){
                JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);
                String categories_name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String categories_id = c.getString(TAG_ID);

                CATEGORY.add(categories_name);
            }
```

this is my setOnChildClickListener where i get the childPosition.

```
// Listview on child click listener
                expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getActivity(),
                                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                        + " : "
                                        + listDataChild.get(
                                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                        childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

this is the complete code

```
package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Fragment used for managing interactions for and presentation of a navigation drawer.
 * See the <a href="https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction">
 * design guidelines</a> for a complete explanation of the behaviors implemented here.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
     * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    String myJSON;
    private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "categories_id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "categories_name";
    JSONArray categories = null;


    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    Boolean InternetAvailable = false;
    Seocnd detectconnection;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View fragmentView =  inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        /*mDrawerListView = (ListView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        //mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                //R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_home),
                        getString(R.string.title_category),
                        getString(R.string.title_myaccount),
                        getString(R.string.title_referafriend),
                        getString(R.string.title_about),
                        getString(R.string.title_privacypocity),
                        getString(R.string.title_shippingterms),
                        getString(R.string.title_contactus),
                }));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);*/

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        //prepareListData();

        detectconnection = new Seocnd(getActivity());
        InternetAvailable = detectconnection.InternetConnecting();
        if (InternetAvailable) {
            getData();
        } else {
            selectItem(100);
        }
        return fragmentView;
    }


    public void getData(){
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://joehamirbalabadan.com/android/android/categories.php");

                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                }
                finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                myJSON=result;
                prepareListData();

                listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

                // setting list adapter
                expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

                // Listview Group click listener
                expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                                int groupPosition, long id) {
            /*Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
            "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                        if(groupPosition == 1){
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            selectItem(groupPosition);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Listview on child click listener
                expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getActivity(),
                                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                        + " : "
                                        + listDataChild.get(
                                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                        childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        g.execute();
    }

    protected void prepareListData(){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            categories = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

            listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
            listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

            // Adding group data
            listDataHeader.add("HOME");
            listDataHeader.add("CATEGORY");
            listDataHeader.add("MY ACCOUNT");
            listDataHeader.add("REFER A FRIEND");
            listDataHeader.add("ABOUT");
            listDataHeader.add("PRIVACY POLICY");
            listDataHeader.add("SHIPPING TERMS");
            listDataHeader.add("CONTACT US");

            List<String> CATEGORY = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=0;i<categories.length();i++){
                JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);
                String categories_name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String categories_id = c.getString(TAG_ID);

                CATEGORY.add(categories_name);
            }

            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), CATEGORY); // Header, Child data

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    /*private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding group data
        listDataHeader.add("HOME");
        listDataHeader.add("CATEGORY");
        listDataHeader.add("MY ACCOUNT");
        listDataHeader.add("REFER A FRIEND");
        listDataHeader.add("ABOUT");
        listDataHeader.add("PRIVACY POLICY");
        listDataHeader.add("SHIPPING TERMS");
        listDataHeader.add("CONTACT US");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> CATEGORY = new ArrayList<String>();
        CATEGORY.add("Category 1");
        CATEGORY.add("Category 2");
        CATEGORY.add("Category 3");
        CATEGORY.add("Category 4");
        CATEGORY.add("Category 5");


        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), CATEGORY); // Header, Child data
}*/

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

ExpandableListAdapter.java

```
package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 9/21/2015.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**NEW QUESTION**

i change my onChildClick here is the code

```
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String header = listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    Category child = listDataChild.get(header).get(childPosition);

    // child.name to get the name
    // child.id to get the id
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"ChildNme: "+child.name+" ChildId: "+child.id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    selectItem(1);

    return false;
}
```

selectItem(1) will go in my MainActivity.

in this part of the code

```
else if (position == 1){
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, CategoryFragment.newInstance())
            .commit();
}
```

then the CategoryFragment will display.

my problem now is how to pass the ChildName and ChildId that solved in previous problem?

i want to pass the ChildName and ChildId to my CategoryFragment

```
package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 9/18/2015.
 */
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

    public static CategoryFragment newInstance() {
        CategoryFragment fragment = new CategoryFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public CategoryFragment () {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categorylayout, container, false);

        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also post your ExpandableListAdapter class code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a Model class (lets say Category), that contains the `name` and the `id`:

```
public class  Category{
    public String name;
    public String id;
}
```

Then load a list of Category object from your json:

```
List<Category> CATEGORY = new ArrayList<Category>();
for(int i=0;i<categories.length();i++){
     JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);
     Category category = new Category();
     category.name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
     category.id = c.getString(TAG_ID);

     CATEGORY.add(category);
 }
```

Finally pass a  `HashMap<String, List<Category>>` as parameter in your adapter instead of `HashMap<String, List<String>>`. And change your adapter methods to support Category object instead of String.

So when you call `getChild()` method, it will return a `Category` object where you can find the `name` and the `id` (`Category.name` , `Category.id`)

**Update**

Change your adapter class to:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<Category>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<Category>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Category getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Category childCategory = (Category) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childCategory.name);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And in your click listener:

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

   @Override
   public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String header = listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
            Category child = listDataChild.get(header).get(childPosition);

            // child.name to get the name
            // child.id to get the id
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"ChildNme: "+child.name+" ChildId: "+child.id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
          }
   });
```

Comment: can you complete the code.. sorry im just new to android.. i got error now in this part  listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), CATEGORY); // Header, Child data

Comment: Make sure that your listDataChild is *HashMap<String, List<Category>>*, sorry i can't re-write your whole code to make the changes, i just give you the idea how you can achieve what you want.

Comment: got this error 09-24 16:33:44.548    3618-3618/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.administrator.mosbeau.Category cannot be cast to java.lang.String
            at com.example.administrator.mosbeau.ExpandableListAdapter.getChildView(ExpandableListAdapter.java:47)

Comment: getChild() will return a Category object not String, so calling (String) getChild() in getChildView() method will cause this exception.

Comment: how to fix this problem? i wait for your answer sir.. you really help me a lot.. thank you very much..

Comment: perfect! thank you very much.. you are awesome and pro.. im glad, because there is a people like you..

Comment: Hi, if you have a new question you should open a new thread not updating an old one.

Comment: check my new question thanks.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776710/how-to-pass-value-from-navigationdrawerfragment-java-to-mainactivity-java-then-p/32777155?noredirect=1#comment53393547_32777155

Comment: Your new question is already answered, and its a correct answer.

Comment: yes but one more question how i display the id and name in my CategoryFragment? i have two EditText in my categorylayout the tpid and tpname..

Comment: hi rami, do you have tutorial or any idea on how to do this?
http://yonand.blogspot.com/2015/03/android-aplikasi-e-commerce-jsonparser.html

Comment: hi rami can you help me with this problem.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835287/android-studio-getjson-php-file-not-working thanks..