# Android Studio ListViewAdapter Error

Tags: android

please help me with this problem..

i change my previous question to this..

i cant post new question because im in danger of being blocked..

heres my problem..

im trying to get data from database but i got this error when i run the app..

```
    09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? E/Error﹕ No value for result
09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for result
09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.administrator.mosbeau.CategoryFragment.prepareListData(CategoryFragment.java:249)
09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.administrator.mosbeau.CategoryFragment$1GetDataJSON.onPostExecute(CategoryFragment.java:233)
09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.administrator.mosbeau.CategoryFragment$1GetDataJSON.onPostExecute(CategoryFragment.java:180)
09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5494)
09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691)
09-29 13:41:07.032  26507-26507/? W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-29 13:41:07.042  26507-26507/? I/MemoryCache﹕ MemoryCache will use up to 24.0MB
09-29 13:41:07.042  26507-26507/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-29 13:41:07.042  26507-26507/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418e38e0)
09-29 13:41:07.042  26507-26507/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.administrator.mosbeau.ListViewAdapter.getCount(ListViewAdapter.java:38)
            at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:463)
            at com.example.administrator.mosbeau.CategoryFragment$1GetDataJSON.onPostExecute(CategoryFragment.java:236)
            at com.example.administrator.mosbeau.CategoryFragment$1GetDataJSON.onPostExecute(CategoryFragment.java:180)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5494)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-29 13:41:07.052     941-7799/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Notify an ApplicationCrash
```

here is the code..

CategoryFragment.java

```
package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 9/18/2015.
 */
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

    public static CategoryFragment newInstance(String id,String name) {
        CategoryFragment fragment = new CategoryFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("id", id);
        bundle.putString("name", name);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }

    public CategoryFragment () {
    }

    EditText tpid, tpname;
    String cid;
    String cname;

    String myJSON;
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView productlistview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static final String result="result";
    static String products_id = "products_id";
    static String products_name = "products_name";
    static String products_price = "products_price";
    static String products_image = "products_image";

    Boolean InternetAvailable = false;
    Seocnd detectconnection;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categorylayout, container, false);

        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

        tpid = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tpid);
        tpname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tpname);

        if(getArguments() != null) {
            String catid = getArguments().getString("id");
            String catname = getArguments().getString("name");

            tpid.setText(catid);
            tpname.setText(catname);
            cid = catid;
            cname = catname;
        }

        productlistview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.productlistview);

        //new DownloadJSON().execute();

        detectconnection = new Seocnd(getActivity());
        InternetAvailable = detectconnection.InternetConnecting();
        if (InternetAvailable) {
            getProduct();
        } else {
            NointernetFragment fragment = new NointernetFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    public void getProduct(){
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                // Set progressdialog title
                mProgressDialog.setTitle(cname);
                // Set progressdialog message
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                // Show progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://joehamirbalabadan.com/android/android/products.php");

                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                }
                finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                myJSON=result;
                prepareListData();
                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);
                // Set the adapter to the ListView
                productlistview.setAdapter(adapter);
                // Close the progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        g.execute();
    }

    protected void prepareListData(){
        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            jsonarray = jsonObj.getJSONArray(result);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject p = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.put("products_id", p.getString("products_id"));
                map.put("products_name", p.getString("products_name"));
                map.put("products_price", p.getString("products_price"));
                map.put("products_image", p.getString("products_image"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(2);
    }
}
```

ListViewAdapter.java

```
package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 9/28/2015.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
                           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView products_id;
        TextView products_name;
        TextView products_price;
        ImageView products_image;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_listview_item, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in product_listview_item.xml
        products_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.products_id);
        products_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.products_name);
        products_price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.products_price);

        // Locate the ImageView in product_listview_item.xml
        products_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.products_image);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        products_id.setText(resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_id));
        products_name.setText(resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_name));
        products_price.setText(resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_price));
        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_image), products_image);
        // Capture ListView item click
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Get the position
                resultp = data.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass all data rank
                intent.putExtra("products_id", resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_id));
                // Pass all data country
                intent.putExtra("products_name", resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_name));
                // Pass all data population
                intent.putExtra("products_price",resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_price));
                // Pass all data flag
                intent.putExtra("products_image", resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_image));
                // Start SingleItemView Class
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

**NEW ERROR**

```
09-29 14:12:26.981      593-593/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409bf1f8)
09-29 14:12:26.992      593-593/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.administrator.mosbeau.CategoryFragment.prepareListData(CategoryFragment.java:259)
            at com.example.administrator.mosbeau.CategoryFragment$1GetDataJSON.onPostExecute(CategoryFragment.java:232)
            at com.example.administrator.mosbeau.CategoryFragment$1GetDataJSON.onPostExecute(CategoryFragment.java:179)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
```

this is line 259

```
            arraylist.add(map);
```

line 232

```
            prepareListData();
```

**UPDATED CODE**

CategoryFragment.java

```
package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 9/18/2015.
 */
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

    public static CategoryFragment newInstance(String id,String name) {
        CategoryFragment fragment = new CategoryFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("id", id);
        bundle.putString("name", name);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }

    public CategoryFragment () {
    }

    EditText tpid, tpname;
    String cid;
    String cname;

    String myJSON;
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView productlistview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    public static String products_id = "products_id";
    public static String products_name = "products_name";
    public static String products_price = "products_price";
    public static String products_image = "products_image";

    Boolean InternetAvailable = false;
    Seocnd detectconnection;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categorylayout, container, false);

        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

        tpid = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tpid);
        tpname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tpname);

        if(getArguments() != null) {
            String catid = getArguments().getString("id");
            String catname = getArguments().getString("name");

            tpid.setText(catid);
            tpname.setText(catname);
            cid = catid;
            cname = catname;
        }

        productlistview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.productlistview);

        //new DownloadJSON().execute();

        detectconnection = new Seocnd(getActivity());
        InternetAvailable = detectconnection.InternetConnecting();
        if (InternetAvailable) {
            getProduct();
        } else {
            NointernetFragment fragment = new NointernetFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    public void getProduct(){
        class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                // Set progressdialog title
                mProgressDialog.setTitle(cname);
                // Set progressdialog message
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                // Show progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://joehamirbalabadan.com/android/android/products.php");

                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                }
                finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                myJSON=result;

                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
                    jsonarray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("products");

                    arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject p = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        map.put("products_id", p.getString("products_id"));
                        map.put("products_name", p.getString("products_name"));
                        map.put("products_price", p.getString("products_price"));
                        map.put("products_image", p.getString("products_image"));
                        // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                        arraylist.add(map);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);
                // Set the adapter to the ListView
                productlistview.setAdapter(adapter);
                // Close the progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        DownloadJSON g = new DownloadJSON();
        g.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(2);
    }
}
```

the image is not displaying when i use the .php file in this code..

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://joehamirbalabadan.com/android/android/products.php");
```

but when i use the .txt file it works..

i tried to copy the data of products.php and save it as .txt then when i change the link to this http://joehamirbalabadan.com/android/android/products.txt..

it works.. but i want to use the .php file because i use this to get the data from database..

products.php result

[image]

products.txt result

[image]

please help me..

Comment: Please don't expect people read tutorials and explain it. If you are having some trouble with php code, please post the relevent bits of PHP code with the error you are seeing. Android code is irrelevent.

Comment: ok i edit my post thanks..

Comment: Any error you are getting when calling .php file ?

Comment: no error just the image is not displaying.. please see edit..

Comment: i follow this tutorial.. http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Comment: ok, but i would suggest you to use ImageLoading libraries like `UniveralImageLoader` or `Picasso` to handle the image loading stuff and they also provide caching mechanism making this stuff easier to handle

Comment: i edit my question.. please help me to fix that problem.. thanks..

Comment: jsonarray = jsonObj.getJSONArray(result); error at this line. Because you are getting jsonData from server not have any "result" array in it.

Comment: thanks.. got new error.. please see edit..

Comment: I think you have not initialize arraylist,where you initialize arraylist?

Comment: in the categoryfragment.. ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist; and please ListViewAdapter in my code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to initialize arraylist first and also create HashMap item new instance inside for loop like  :

```
protected void prepareListData(){
    try {
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Locate the array name in JSON
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        jsonarray = jsonObj.getJSONArray(result);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject p = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            // Retrive JSON Objects
            map.put("products_id", p.getString("products_id"));
            map.put("products_name", p.getString("products_name"));
            map.put("products_price", p.getString("products_price"));
            map.put("products_image", p.getString("products_image"));
            // Set the JSON Objects into the array
            arraylist.add(map);
        }
    catch (JSONException e) {
       Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
       e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your result string with products like this one:

```
static final String result="products";
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to decalre below variables

```
static final String result="result";
static String products_id = "products_id";
static String products_name = "products_name";
static String products_price = "products_price";
static String products_image = "products_image";
```

which you have to change like this

```
public static final String result="result";
public static String products_id = "products_id";
public static String products_name = "products_name";
public static String products_price = "products_price";
public static String products_image = "products_image";
```

I hope it work.